# Setting up custom DC/OS installation across various networks

Tags: networking, azure

I have 5 VPS Servers on azure spanning different resource groups (3 groups) I want a way to install DC/OS and configure it in such a way that it can well work.

basically my question is can DC/OS be configured when servers are on different `virtual networks`?

i do have access to each with ssh and all of them have static IP-Addresses

Comment: any particular reason to have those resources into separated vnets?

Comment: we get azure credits for each account and we would like to use the credits instead of spending money. so they are basically on different account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is communication between the servers. It doesn't matter if they are in the same subscription or network. As long as they are in the same datacenter, you shouldn't have any issues regarding lag or timeouts. These are the best options I see:

1) VNet peering

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-network-peering-overview/

2) Site-to-site VPN (VNet to VNet)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-vnet-vnet-rm-ps/

Comment: VNet peering is still in Test mode i was unable to get access to it but I have connected with the second method and can now ping the local IPs with a lag of 2 to 3 ms. so that should not be a problem.

thanks a lot.